# Create custom hyperlinks in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2011

I am looking for a formula to automatically create custom hyperlinks into an excel spreadsheet, based on contents of another cell

I have a list of books where I can get the image from an url database. It's the same URL for all books, just the ISBN number i different.

The numbers are also the ISBN number, so I want excel to create a hyperlink based on the contents of cell A (the numbers in bold).

CELL A (ISBN):

**9788700396241**

CELL B

Hyperlink: https://images.website.com/images/**9788700396241**.jpg

How can I make excel change the ISBN number in the URL for all rows?

Thanks.

Comment: To accept the solution all you have to do is click the check-mark, and up one if you found it useful. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It's a fairly straightforward solution.

The format is this:

Let A1=9788700396241
=**HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(**"https://images.website.com/images/",A1,".jpg"**)**,"LINK"**)**

or

=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1),"LINK")

where A1=root_link, B1=image_name, C1=image extension (.jpg)